# VS Code FTP Simple working as Atom FTP Edit

Tags: ftp, visual-studio-code, atom-editor

I have been using Atom for a long time, at the end it has been just for comfort but for the last few weeks I have been using VS Code, and I am delighted with the IDE, so I want to completely migrate to it.

But the only thing I'm missing from VS Code is the functionality that atom has with the ftp (ftp edit) plugin that allows me to navigate through the ftp directory without previously downloading the files, just when I open files or directories the IDE perse. Instead, the plugin ftp-simple of VS Code doesn't allow me to use this functionality (or at least I haven't know how to find it) so I have to download the entire ftp tree, and on each connection I have to wait as long as it takes to get off.

Any idea about this configuration or if this is any parameter in some config file?

Thank you!!! :)

Comment: Did you mean this extension https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=humy2833.ftp-simple?

Comment: @Biswapriyo yes, that one. I don't know if I have to look for another extension

Comment: I'm also amazed that VS code does not have a built-in solution for this (like dreamweaver etc)... I'm also an Atom user and can't migrate to VS code because this is not available. Really strange.. The suggest extension has many problems/bugs.